# Alternating Series Error Bound Formula Derivation

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm learning about error approximations in my AP Calc. BC class, was given this formula (from Shaw and Taylor Calculus Extended) to define the alternating series error bound:

$$ASR ≤ |\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$$

which is like the Lagrange remainder bound where z=c.

The alternating series error bound is also defined as the next unused term, which means that $a_{n+1} = |\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$
.

I haven't been able to resolve any intuition or find any answers as to why these two are equal. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $(a_n)$ are the terms of the Taylor series of $f$ around $c$, then $|a_{n+1}|$ is by definition the formula that you've written down. What's the problem?

Comment: @JackM I was wondering less about how $|\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$ equates to the next term in the Taylor series (because that's the definition), and more about how, for many alternating series except sin and cos, ASR = LR or $|\frac{f^{n+1}(c)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$ = $|\frac{f^{n+1}(z)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}|$. How does the maximum $f^{n+1}(z)$ equal the n+1 derivative about the center c $f^{n+1}(c)$ for these alternating series? Is there a common property found in these alternating series that makes it this way?

Comment: Do you have an example of a Taylor series for which ASR=LR?

Comment: @JackM Yeah, $e^{-x} = 1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}$.